# Finding the closest point to a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Hello differential geometry community!

Suppose that I have a smooth Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{N}$ embedded into a Euclidean space $\mathcal{P}$. Assume that I have two position vectors $p_1,p_2 \in \mathcal{N}$; s.t. $p_1 \neq p_2$. Now, imagine the straight line **segment** passing through these two points in $\mathcal{P}$ called, say, $\ell$. Let $p_k \in \ell$. Is it possible to find the shortest line **segment** passing through both $p_k$ and another point in $\mathcal{N}$? It could also be an iterative algorithm like in Newton’s method to find the root; not necessarily a closed form mathematical expression.

By the way there is not limit on the distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$ w.r.t. Euclidean norm in $\mathcal{P}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you want to find $q \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $\|q - p_k\|$ is minimal. I assume that $p_k \notin \mathcal{N}$, or else it is trivial. I also assume that the embedding $\mathcal{N} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{P}$ is proper to avoid weird cases such that, for example, $\mathcal{N} = \left\{\left(1 + \frac{1}{t}\right)e^{it}\mid|t > 0\right\}$ (there is no solution if $p_k = 0$ in this case). If the embedding is proper, the set $K = \mathcal{N} \cap B(p_k,\|p_k - p_1\|)$ is compact so we can find a $q \in K$ that minimises its distance with $p_k$.

Let us endow $\mathcal{N}$ with the metric induced by the Euclidean metric on $\mathcal{P}$. The properness of the injection implies that $\mathcal{N}$ is complete. Let $J : q \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\|q - p_k\|^2$, which is a smooth map $\mathcal{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ that can be extended to $\mathcal{P}$. We are looking for minimas of $J$. More generally, we are looking for critical points.

At a point $q \in \mathcal{N}$, we have an embedding $T_q\mathcal{N} \hookrightarrow T_q\mathcal{P} = \mathcal{P}$ and for all $v \in T_q\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{P}$, $dJ(q)v = \left<q - p_k,v\right>$, which is zero for all $v$ if and only if $q - p_k$ (which is non zero) is orthogonal to any vector of $T_q\mathcal{N}$. Let $\pi_q : \mathcal{P} \twoheadrightarrow T_q\mathcal{N}$ be the orthogonal projection. $q$ is a critical point of $J$ if and only if $\pi_q(q - p_k) = 0$ and in fact, $\nabla J(q) = \pi_q(q - p_k) \in T_q\mathcal{N}$.

Now, to find critical points with a computer, you can try to use the flow of the vector field on $\mathcal{N}$, $X(q) = -\nabla J(q) = -\pi_q(q - p_k) \in T_q\mathcal{N}$. Let $\Phi$ be this flow and $f = J \circ \Phi$.

Let $q_0 \in \mathcal{N}$ and $t$ such that $\Phi(q_0,t)$ exists. We have,
\begin{align*}
\partial_tf(q_0,t) & = \partial_t(J(\Phi(q_0,t)))\\
& = dJ(\Phi(q_0,t))\partial_t\Phi(q_0,t)\\
& = dJ(\Phi(q_0,t))X(\Phi(q_0,t))\\
& = -dJ(\Phi(q_0,t))\nabla J(q_0,t)\\
& = -\|\nabla J(\Phi(q_0,t))\|^2\\
& \leqslant 0.
\end{align*}
In particular, $f(q_0,\cdot)$ is deacreasing so $\Phi$ stays in the compact set $\mathcal{N} \cap B(p_k,\|q_0 - p_k\|)$ (it is compact because $\mathcal{N} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{P}$ is proper), which implies that it is defined for all $t$, $X$ is complete. You can probably prove that each $\Phi(q_0,t)$ converges toward some local minima of $J$ when $t$ diverges toward infinity (maybe you need a few more hypothesis on $\mathcal{N}$, I didn't try to prove it). I hope it helped ! Notice that a local minima is not a golbal one and you might need to change the point $q_0$ to see if you arrive at a better destination, maybe try to change $q_0$ randomly a big amount of times.

Comment: I really appreciate this elegant explanation. That is awesome! I got your point, all of it :) I think, I should move along $X(q)$ via $\exp{(.)}$ map and when I realize $J$ starts to go up, I should stop there. Then, I’ll move to the next point $p_{k+1} \in \ell$ which is $\Delta t$ away from $p_{k}$ and do the same stuff until I hit $p_2$. By doing so, at least I’ll be able to find a suboptimal curve connecting $p_1$ and $p_2$ which is more than enough for me. Of course, after I approximate $X(q)$’s component functions at $T\mathcal{N}_\vert{q_1}, T\mathcal{N}_\vert{q_2}, \dotsc$ :)

Comment: If you want to find a curve that links $p_1$ to $p_2$, I don't think this method will work however :/ Take the extrem case of $\mathcal{N} = \mathbb{S}^n$ is a sphere and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are antipodal. Then, for all $p_k \in [p_1,p_2]$, the optimal $q$ is $p_1$ or $p_2$ in function of which one is the closest (and any point of the sphere fits if $p_k$ is the exact middle of the segment).

Comment: For optimal paths like that you'd better look for geodesics which are smooth paths $\alpha : I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ that verify $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma = 0$ where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection. In local coordinates, it gives you a PDE of order $2$ to solve. Be careful however, geodesics that link two points are not necessarily optimal curves, it depends on $\mathcal{N}$ (but optimal curves are always geodesics).

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment, Cactus. However, the issue is that I will enforce geodesic condition via continuous reinforcement learning after I find a crude, initial curve $\alpha_0(t)$ between $p_1$ and $p_2$. Otherwise; I cannot anchor the starting/ending values for the coefficient function $C$; s.t. $Y(q)=\sum_i^r C^{i}(q)X_i\vert_q \in T\mathcal{N}\vert_q$, where $\mathfrak{g}=\text{span}(X_1,\dotsc,X_r)$. Then I’ll deform this curve into a geodesic using Hamilton-Jacobi-type least action.